# Отступы внутри ячейки

Tags: excel

Всем привет.
После вписывания в ячейку текста Excel располагает этот текст в зависимости от его (текста) характеристик и заданного пользователем форматирования. Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разъясните или дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на документы или статьи MS - как назначаются  внутренние отступы (в px) вписанного текста от границ ячейки, как они  изменяются в зависимости от размера шрифта, горизонтального и вертикального выравнивания, значения левого или правого отступа?
Наверняка применяются какие-то формулы.
Немного уточню.
Excel как оболочка в данном вопросе мне не нужна.
В своей программе формирую экселевские файлы, используя стороннюю библиотеку.
Например, ширину и высоту строки в px я могу вычислить. Ширину столбца я должен вычислять сам. Ширина столбца = ширина строки + доп.пиксели.
Сколько добавлять этих доп.пикселей в зависимости от заданного форматирования?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Справка:

> Увеличение значения в поле Отступ на единицу означает увеличение
>   отступа на ширину одного символа

Береся ширина символа не текущего шрифта, а стандартного, применяемого по умолчанию:

> Стандартный шрифт для текста на листе. Этот шрифт установлен по
>   умолчанию для обычного стиля ячеек.

Ширина отступа не изменится при изменении  в ячейке типа шрифта или его размера:

> Число, показанное в поле Стандартная ширина столбца , является средним
>   числом знаков 0-9 стандартного шрифта..., отображающихся в одной
>   ячейке.

Comment: скриншот в моем вопросе сделан с листа книги, где шрифт по умолчанию я задал Calibri 11.Ну явно размер отступа зависит от размера шрифта.

Comment: скриншот в моем вопросе сделан с листа книги, где шрифт по умолчанию я задал Calibri 11.Ну явно размер отступа зависит от размера шрифта.  Для Calibri 11 ширина символа "8" составляет 7px. Левый отступ 0 -> расстояние от границы до символа - 3px, для отступа 1 - 12px, для 2 - 21px, для 3 - 30px. Получается отступ равен 9px вместо 7px.  И еще. Для отступа 0 от левой границы до символа - 3px. При увеличении размера шрифта это расстояние увеличивается. По каким правилам?